# For a metric $d$ on a group $G$, why do $d$ and $d^{-1}$ generate the same topology.

Tags: topological-groups

Let $d$ be a metric on a group $G$ and define $d^{-1}$ by $d^{-1}(x,y)=d(x^{-1},y^{-1})$.  Why do $d$ and $d^{-1}$ generate the same metric topology on $G$?

Let $g \in G$ and $\epsilon >0$.  Let $B_d=B_d(g,\epsilon)=\{h \in G : d(g,h) < \epsilon\}$.  I need to find a $d^{-1}$ ball inside of $B_d$ but am having trouble.  Did I set the problem up correctly?

Any hints/solutions are appreciated here.

Comment: I suppose $G$ is a topological group in the topology induced by $d$? Otherwise, the conclusion would not necessarily hold. If $d$ makes $G$ a topological group, the inversion $x \mapsto x^{-1}$ is by definition of a topological group a homeomorphism.

Comment: It must be a typo then, I will close the question soon.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are missing an assumption. Your metric shouldn't be any old metric on the set of elements of $G$, it needs to respect the group structure.

For example, taking the inverse of an element should be *continuous* function with regards to $d$. How could you use that continuity to find a $\epsilon_2$ such that $B_{d^{-1}}(g,\epsilon_2)\subset B_d(g,\epsilon)$?